# Определить количество элементов между первым и последним нулевыми элементами

Tags: c++

В двумерном массиве определить к-во элементов между первым и последним нулевыми элементами.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r,c, i, j, count=0;
    cout << "\n Input number of rows: "; cin >> r;
    cout << " Input number of columns: "; cin >> c;
    cout << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int **m = new int* [r];
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[c];  }

    for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[c];
        for (j=0; j<c; j++)  {
            m[i][j] = rand()%100-0; cout << " " << m[i][j] << "\t";  }
        cout << endl;  }
    cout << endl;

    int i1 = -1, j1 = -1, i2 = -1, j2 = -1;
    bool foundTwoZeros = false;

    for (i=0; i<r; i++)  {
        for (j=0; j<c; j++)  {
            if (m[i][j]==0)
                if (i1 == -1 && j1 == -1)
                {
                    i1 = i;  j1 = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    i1 = i;  j2 = j;
                    foundTwoZeros = true;
                    goto foundTwoZeros;
                }
        }
    }

    foundTwoZeros:

    if (foundTwoZeros)   {
         int pos1 = c * i1 + j1;
         int pos2 = c * i2 + j2;
         count = pos2 - pos1 - 1;

         cout << "\n Total of elements between the first and last zero element: " << count << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
         cout << "\n There are not two zero elements";
    }

    for (i=0; i<r; i++)  {
        delete [] m[i];
    }
    delete []m;

    _getch();
}
```

Программа компилируется, но ответ не правильно когда есть два нуля. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: где у вас присваивается `i2`? Возможно опечатка  в строке: `i1 = i;  j2 = j;`

Comment: Наверное проще всего найти сначала первый (как Вы и делаете, двигаясь от начала к концу), а затем последний (в аналогичных вложенных циклах, но двигаясь от конца к началу). Кстати, если первый не найден, то второй можно уже не искать. И обратите внимание, первый и последний могут совпадать, если в массиве ровно один нулевой элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с мелочи - вы два раза выделяете память для строк:

```
for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    m[i] = new int[c];  }
```

а потом, сразу же -

```
for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    m[i] = new int[c];
```

Потом, здесь

```
    i1 = i;  j2 = j;
```

явно надо `i2 = i;`

И еще - крайне рекомендую избавиться от `goto` - например, так:

```
for (i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        if (m[i][j]==0)
        {
            if (i1 == -1 && j1 == -1)
            {
                i1 = i;  j1 = j;
            }
            else
            {
                i2 = i;  j2 = j;
                foundTwoZeros = true;
                break;             //#####
            }
        }
    }
    if (foundTwoZeros) break;    //#####
}
```

Comment: Не надо выходить из цикла. По условию задачи человеку нужен **последний** ноль.

Comment: @Zealint Посмотрите в его цикл - у него там выход из цикла. Мой код эквивалентен коду автора, просто без goto. Правильно ли это - это второй вопрос :)

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, здесь " i1 = i;  j2 = j;"  была ошибка, но возникает проблема, если есть три нуля, код только определит к-во элементов между первым и второй нулевыми элементами.

Comment: @Nas_04 А на это вам ответил **@Zeliant** - не выходите преждевременно из цикла, как только найдете два нуля. Ищите до конца. В предложенном мною в ответе коде уберите строки, помеченные `//#####`

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, за Вас никто программу не напишет. Могу только указать на ряд очевидных ошибок, думаю, исправив их, получите работающий код.

1. Память у Вас почему-то выделяется дважды, будьте внимательны.
2. Вы ошиблись в блоке else внутри двойного цикла. Во-первых, там нужно присваивать i2, а не i1. Во-вторых, выходить из блока нельзя, потому что так вы ищите только второй ноль, а по условию нужно искать последний (их же может быть 3 и больше).

Общая рекомендации, если только учитесь программировать - никогда не копируйте код. Впрочем, даже опытные программисты ошибаются, пытаясь сэкономить эти 5 секунд времени.